# I am showing the list of elements in Alert-box by using the setMultiChoiceItems, But when ever i am scrolling the checkbox are dismissed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have implemented the Alert dialogue with checkbox and item name, I am not using any custom adapter to show the list view.I am able to display the items with checked states successfully but my problem is when ever i scroll the  alertbox some of checkbox are unchecked.Could please suggest me how can i resolve this issue.
Please find the code for showing alert box with MultiChoiceItems.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this)
        .setOnCancelListener(this)
          .setTitle("title")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(nameofItems, Checkedstates, listner);
                 mDialog = builder.create();
                  mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll list it update the view using data list so if you want your back check status, you have to update data list as well. Update your data list by using DialogInterface OnMultiChoiceClickListener.

```
OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        Checkedstates[which] = isChecked;    
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am not selected any checkbox without selecting any checkbox already selected checkbox is unchecked when scrolling the  dialog.

Comment: Could you please upload the Activity to which Dialog belong